# Ranking with end state conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

```
ID  Initial_State   End_State   Date                  Rank
12345   B           EndState    22/08/2019 08:58    3
12345   EndState2          B    21/08/2019 08:58    3
12345   B          EndState2    20/08/2019 08:58    2
12345   EndState           B    19/08/2019 08:58    2
12345   B           EndState    18/08/2019 08:58    1
12345   A                  B    17/08/2019 08:58    1
```

In the above table I am trying to create the rank column. Rank should be assigned based on the State. If any end state is encountered, then the rank must change and be added by 1.
For example, one ID can have multiple states, however when an end state is encountered, all transitions below it should be considered as rank one.

I am using MYSQL

Comment: please [edit] your question to tag your specific RDBMS.

Comment: Please add your code to your question and indicate where you are stuck.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing.  You have a value `'EndState'` and a column `End_State`.  What are you referring to?

Comment: The column content 'EndState'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with window functions.  You can count the number of "end states" up to the *previous* row and add 1:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(sum(case when End_State like 'EndState%' then 1 else 0 end) over
                    (partition by id
                     order by date
                     rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                    )
                   ), 0
                ) + 1 as rank
from t;
```

Comment: but OP didn't mention whether he uses version 8+